# Adding an HTML class to a Sphinx directive with an extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm trying to write a basic extension to create a new directive (`output`) based on the `only` directive [provided by Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html#including-content-based-on-tags). This new directive simply needs to add an HTML class to the standard result of the `Only` directive.

So for this I have tried the following code based on this [collapse-code-block extension](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/sphinxext/collapsible_code_block.py).

Since docutils has virtually no documentation and that I'm not a very experienced python developer, I'm struggling to make this work.

Here is what I have tried, amongst other variations that all led to no real indication on the issue:

```py
from docutils import nodes

from sphinx.directives.other import Only


class output_node(nodes.General, nodes.Element):
    pass


class output_directive(Only):

    option_spec = Only.option_spec

    def run(self):
        env = self.state.document.settings.env

        node = output_node()
        output = Only.run(self)
        node.setup_child(output)
        node.append(output)

        return [node]


def html_visit_output_node(self, node):
    self.body.append(self.starttag(node, 'div', '', CLASS='internalonly'))


def html_depart_output_node(self, node):
    self.body.append('</div>')


def setup(app):
    app.add_node(
        output_node,
        html=(
            html_visit_output_node,
            html_depart_output_node
        )
    )
    app.add_directive('output', output_directive)
```

I don't think it should be more complicated than that but this just doesn't cut it.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not use the [`:class:` attribute](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class)? In Sphinx it is called [`rst-class`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#id1).

Comment: That would mean more chances of errors. With an extension, I control the output class name, not the user.

Comment: Hey Flag, the code from your question has helped me a lot to generate custom container (div with custom tags) that I needed for my custom directive. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "this just doesn't cut it"?